# Finding when $x(t)=3e^{-t/50}-3e^{-t/5}$ is greater than $1.5$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following equation:

$$x(t)=3e^{-t/50}-3e^{-t/5}$$

where $t$ is in hours.

I need to find when $x(t)\geq 1.5$.

Can anyone help me in starting this off?

Comment: Please see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Fractions do not look nice in exponents. In this case, there is no need to use \frac{a}{b}.

Comment: You changed the equation... $-t/5$ or $+t/5$???

Comment: My bad: it should be $-t/5$.

Comment: Define $y=e^{-t/5}$.  Then you have $x=3y^{10}-3y$, which is more tractable.  It is still a numeric solution if you want the crossing points.

Comment: A simple trick:  divide both sides by $3$.  Can you see why that simplifies everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a graph that shows the solutions:

[image]

Divide both sides of the equation by $3$, then define $e^{-t/50} = q$ and recast the equation as:

$$q - q^{10} = 1/2$$

which has solution $q = 0.500996$ and $0.916037$.  Then solve for $t = -50 \ln q$:

$$4.384 \leq t \leq 33.6711$$.

Answer (score 0):

Dividing by $3$, consider that you look for the zero of function
$$f(t)=e^{-t/50}-e^{-t/5}-\frac 12$$ Letting $y=e^{-t/50}$ would lead to a polynomial of degree $10$ in $y$ and this does not show analytical solution. So, a numerical method is required.

First, you must show thet $f(t)$ is an increasing function (I let you proving it - it is simple) to prove that the solution is unique.

Since you will use a numerical method, you need a starting guess. Hoping that the solution is small, expand as a Taylor series to get
$$f(t)=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{9 t}{50}+O\left(t^2\right)$$ which gives $t_0=\frac{25}{9}$. Start Newton method for the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & t_n \\
 0 & 2.77778 \\
 1 & 4.11131 \\
 2 & 4.37580 \\
 3 & 4.38489 \\
 4 & 4.38490
\end{array}
\right)$$

ANother solution could be to consider
$$g(t)=-\frac t {50}-\log \left(\frac{1}{2}+e^{-t/5}+\right)$$ which is much more linear. Expanding again as series would give
$$g(t)=-\log \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)+\frac{17 t}{150}+O\left(t^2\right)$$  from which $$t_0=\frac{150}{17} \log \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\approx 3.5776$$ which is much closer. Newton method again for the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & t_n \\
 0 & 3.57763 \\
 1 & 4.34367 \\
 2 & 4.38478 \\
 3 & 4.38490
\end{array}
\right)$$